# How to set one variable to another in same line without globalizing

Tags: javascript

In this situation:

```
(function() {
   const a = b = 10;
})();
console.log('a:', a); // ReferenceError: a is not defined
console.log('b:', b); // 10
```

The `b` gets defined as a `var` in the global scope. Is it possible o do this equals trick but make `b` a `const` as well in the same scope? Just like `a`?

Comment: please fix your snippet. the snippet you provided throws error `ReferenceError: b is not defined` and even if it didn't (perhaps in a different JS engine?) you still can't access `const` identifiers outside of their lexical scope

Answer (score 1):

You could set `b` as a parameter to your IIFE function. That way `b` won't be accessible outside of function scope.

```js
(function(b) {
   const a = b = 10;
   console.log(b)
})();


console.log('b:', b);
```

Comment: Cool trick! Thanks I was studying for interview questions and they didn't ask how to fix, they just expected us to know that `b` got globalized, but i was curious how to fix.

Comment: Just as a sidenote, `const` has a block scope so if you just use simple if block `a` scope is limited to that block but you couldn't use this solution in that case https://jsfiddle.net/gpza6cx0/1/

Comment: thanks Nenad! Very helpful!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. This "trick" is possible because `b = 10` returns `10`. However, `const b = 10` returns `undefined`.

Why not just use:

```
const a = 10;
const b = a;
```

?

It's not slower, and it's more readable, even if you could nest the assignments I don't really see a reason to do it

Comment: Thanks I was studying for interview questions and they didn't ask how to fix, they just expected us to know that `b` got globalized, but i was curious how to fix.